# Minimal requirements for a function to be expandable in separable functions

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, functions

To proceed my work on my Master's thesis in physics I need to know the following:
Let $F(x,y,u^{(n)},v^{(m)})$ be a real function of independent variables $x,y \in \Omega \subset \mathbb{R}$ and dependent variables $u^{(n)},v^{(m)}$ that is smooth in all of its arguments, where $u^{(n)}$ denotes some sufficiently smooth function $u(x)$ and its various derivatives $u_{x},u_{xx},...$ up to order $n$ (analogously for $v$ depending on $y$). However, consider them as being completely different coordinates.
Which additional requirements on $F$ are necessary to write it as a linear combination of products of smooth functions $f_{i}$ and $g_{i}$ each depending only on the following arguments: $f_{i}=f_{i}(x,u^{(n)})$ and $g_{i}=g_{i}(y,v^{(m)})$? That is to say:

$$F(x,y,u^{(n)},v^{(m)})=\sum_{i=0}^\infty a_{i} \; f_{i}(x,u^{(n)}) \; g_{i}(y,v^{(m)}).$$

I was already thinking about analytic functions but I do not really know how to tackle such problems. Any hint or reference would be helpful.
Thanks in advance!

Edit: Even for a simpler version like a restriction to the variables $x$ and $y$, it would be still nice to know the largest class of functions for which the statement remains true. I highly appreciate your efforts!